# Vehicle power systems - prior art request

Tags: prior-art-request, pre-grant, us20120124571, vehicle, power-supply

Could the community help by supplying a relevant **manual for a vehicle power system**?  Any vehicle, could be **any make or model of car**. It should show the power supply available to the accessories, such as on-board computer, during states such as car off, brake pedal depressed, key in ignition, starting car, driving, and so on.

This patent application uses characteristics of a vehicle power supply to decide when to download software updates to the on-board computer.  **The power supply conditions are illustrated in figure 3** and other figures.

Answer (score 1):

I have the service manual for a 1987 Honda Civic. There are three sections I've made a copy of:

1. [Electrical Service](https://onedrive.live.com/download.aspx?resid=AA7F13B575BFA25!4642)
2. [Electrical Wiring Diagrams](https://onedrive.live.com/download.aspx?resid=AA7F13B575BFA25!4641)
3. [Electrical Troubleshooting](https://onedrive.live.com/download.aspx?resid=AA7F13B575BFA25!4643)

Of the three, it would seem to me that the Troubleshooting section would be of the most help, since it describes the state of the electrical system when certain conditions are present (so you can determine where the fault is occurring). Unfortunately, this section had some problems when it was originally scanned, and some of the pages are just black on the bottom, due to corrupted data. Most of the 326 pages of information is accessible.

Hopefully they can all be of help. Leave me a comment if you would like to see if I can get a copy of a manual for the electrical system of a newer vehicle.

Comment: @HHill Did that do the job? I can get another manual if the blank pages are an issue, or if the information you're looking for isn't there.